# Angular2: PathLocationStrategy + hash/anchor

Tags: routes, angular

Is there a way to add an anchor (something like `#myelementid`) to a link in a `[routerLink]` attribute when using `PathLocationStrategy`? The purpose is to navigate between views and hilite a specific element, of which there may be dozens on the target page.

Basically, what I am looking for is this:

```
<a [routerLink]="['RouteName'] + '#myelementid'">
```

Except, of course, that this does not work ;-)

Comment: I assume you have, but have you tried using a regular anchor tag rather than a routerLink? `<a href="#myelementid">Highlight</a>`

Comment: The element I would like to link to is on a different page, therefore this won’t work.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you run into this issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6595 (and https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7215)

I haven't seen any workaround.

Comment: Not quite. When I manually open `http://myUrl/#myelementid`, the element in question is hilited as intended – via CSS3 `:target` –, despite Angular (Beta13) removing the hash from the URL. So, my primary problem ist to somehow get the hash into the URL via `routerLink`.